# Sharkoon 5-Bay RAID Box, will it play?

Tags: raid, external-hdd, compatibility, lvm

I'm looking to expand the storage capacity of my home server running on Ubuntu Server Edition.
Because the server is a small sized mini-ITX cube with room for only 1 HDD, I had the idea of installing the OS disk in the server and attach N external hard disks as 1 large logical volume with USB3.

So I started looking around for external drive bays that could hold more than 1 disk and this http://www.sharkoon.com/?q=en/node/1809 system caught my eye.

However, the product information only says that the system is compatible with Windows.
It also provides details about the chipset used, being JMicron JMB393 and JMB 539.
The JMicron website FAQ says the chipset is compatible with Linux but I would like to be 100% sure before purchasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That raid box uses USB and eSata to connect to the host pc and does not need other software to operate.

The RAID mode and configuration is done by jumpers on the back of the box

[image]

That means that the host computer will not really mather as long as it can support USB or eSata and those are present in any recent motherboard and supported by Linux, thus support by Ubuntu.

You can have a look at the manual [here](http://www.sharkoon.com/sites/default/files/ddblock/nid-1805/images/manual_en_15995.pdf), it describes the setup, possibles configuration of the raid box, all software independent.

Answer (score 1):

It works beautifully on my Windows 7 laptop. It disconnects after about 20 mins on mu Ubuntu 14.04 i5 NUC.

Am still investigating how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

Having spoken to Sharkoon tech support, they says it's only supported on Windows.

This is probably due to the JMicron 539 USB 3.0 controller, which is in a number of similar devices and is notorious for problems with both Mac OS and Linux.